# Given column vectors $x$ and $y$, show that the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ must be singular if $Ax = Ay$, and $x \neq y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm not entirely sure how to solve this one. The textbook that this is from is asking this question without showing any method for checking if a matrix is invertible, or how to calculate the inverse of a matrix. All it has shown so far is the definition of an inverse matrix. I'm not sure how to use that to solve this.

I suspect that it is because (I think, anyways) $A$ must be the zero matrix which would be singular. But I don't know how I can prove that $A$ must always be singular.

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily the zero matrix.

Comment: Hint: If $x\neq y$ then the kernel of $A$ is not $\{0\}.$

Comment: @Matematleta I don't know what a kernel is. My textbook has not covered that as of yet.

Comment: Hint: if $A$ is non-singular and $Az=0$ what does this say about $z$?

Comment: I think you can do the following. ( but I'm open to being corrected ).  Assume that $A$  is not singular. Then multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. This implies that $x = y$ which is a contradiction to the original assumption that $x \neq y$.

Comment: @Matematleta I'm not sure... Perhaps either A or z could be a zero matrix?

Comment: @markleeds This seems like a decent way to do it!

Comment: Set $z=x-y.$ Then $z\neq 0.$ On the other hand. if $A$ is non-singular, then it is invertible. But now, $A^{-1}Az=0\Rightarrow z=0,\ $ a contradiction.

Comment: @Kalcifer: Thanks for confirmation. It's appreciated.